# Perforce post-user-edit trigger not working, works as pre-user-edit

Tags: python, version-control, triggers, perforce

I am attempting to create a post-user-edit trigger to display a warning message depending on the file that is marked for edit. I would like to do this by having the trigger fail and then the client will display the failure message.

My trigger is now torn down to just a bare print statement for debugging purposes. I've written the trigger in python and it simply prints "Hello" then returns 1 (failure) in order to trigger the client to display the trigger validation message.

This works wonderfully when the trigger is set to pre-user-edit, I see that "TestTrigger" validation failed and the client shows the "Hello" message. However, as soon as I swap this trigger to run post-edit, I get a "": Validation failed. It does not properly list my trigger name and also does not print out my "Hello" message.

Is there any nuances to working with post triggers? Unsure of what I could be doing wrong.

Here is a sample of what I am using:

Triggers file:

```
Triggers:
    TestTrigger command post-user-edit "/usr/bin/python %//Path/To/triggerTest.py%"
```

Trigger itself:

```
import sys

def run():
    print "Hello"
    return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(run())
```

Failure message, sensitive info blacked out
[image: Failure message, sensitive info blacked out]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the actual problem you're hitting, but you don't need to return a failure; I'm not even sure what a "failure" on a post-command trigger would mean since the command has already happened.  :)

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 triggers -o | tail -n2
        edit command post-user-edit "echo Edit!"


C:\Perforce\test>p4 edit foo
//stream/main/foo#4 - currently opened for edit
Edit!
```

Since you're not getting any output, I'm guessing the problem is actually that the trigger isn't running, due to a typo in the path or something like that.  The server log file might have clues.

Comment: I agree that it seems like the trigger isn't actually running. I don't believe it's a path issue since I can use the exact same trigger line and just change "post" to "pre" and the trigger runs correctly. I will try to look at the server logs to get more information.

Comment: Other things to try that might help narrow down the problem: change the script to return 0, try doing the edit from the command line instead of P4V